# how to append data into file when jButton is pressed

Tags: java

I have been creating a GUI app that registers data for student, data are filled in the JTextfields provided. Upon pressing the submit button, i have programmed it to store the data into a file at A certain manner(Arrangement) that i prefer. For the first submission, the program works well and stores data into the file, ***but on other successive`enter code here` submissions(i.e when the student re-fills) the program either overwrites or doesn't write at all into the file***. Below is the code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class StudentAssignment extends JFrame {
    private JLabel lblFname, lblbSname, lblRegNo, lblPos;
    private JButton btnsubmit;
    private JTextField txtFname, txtSname, txtRegNo, txtPos;
    private JPanel panel1, panel12, panel3, panel4,panel5;
    private int i = 1;
    private File myFile;
    private FileWriter fw;
    private PrintStream ps;


    public StudentAssignment() throws Exception{
        componentInitialization();
        setVisible(true);

        myFile =new File("Mustard.txt");

        fw = new FileWriter(myFile,true);
        ps = new PrintStream(myFile);

        actionListeners();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void componentInitialization(){
        setBounds(200, 200, 300, 300);
        setTitle("Mustard's Frame");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

        lblFname = new JLabel("First Name");
        txtFname = new JTextField(10);
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(lblFname); panel1.add(txtFname);

        lblbSname = new JLabel("Surname");
        txtSname = new JTextField(10);
        panel12 = new JPanel();
        panel12.add(lblbSname); panel12.add(txtSname);

        lblRegNo = new JLabel("Registration Number");
        txtRegNo = new JTextField(10);
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.add(lblRegNo); panel3.add(txtRegNo);

        lblPos = new JLabel("program of study");
        txtPos = new JTextField(10);
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel4.add(lblPos); panel4.add(txtPos);

        btnsubmit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
        panel5 = new JPanel();
        panel5.add(btnsubmit);

        add(panel1); add(panel12);
        add(panel3); add(panel4);
        add(panel5);

    }

    public void actionListeners(){

        btnsubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

                try {
                    fileStoring();
                }catch (Exception exc){

                }

                clearFields();
            }
        });
    }

    public void fileStoring() throws Exception{

        System.setOut(ps);

        System.out.printf("%-10s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", "Sno.", "First Name", "Surname", "Reg.No", "Program of Study");
        System.out.printf("%-10d %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",i,txtFname.getText(), txtSname.getText(), txtRegNo.getText(), txtPos.getText()  );
        i++;
        fw.close();
        ps.close();
    }

    public void clearFields(){
        txtFname.setText("");
        txtSname.setText("");
        txtRegNo.setText("");
        txtPos.setText("");

        txtFname.requestFocus();
    }

    public static  void  main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        StudentAssignment obj = new StudentAssignment();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `System.setOut(ps);`? You have a `PrintStream`, just use that directly. You will also need to reopen the file before writing to it. You should really take a look at [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Try moving   fw = new FileWriter(myFile,true);
    ps = new PrintStream(myFile); to the begining of fileStoring () method. Its probably because you're closing them if you reinstantiate them each time you use them it should work

Comment: @MadProgrammer   System.setout(ps) writes the entire following lines of the code into a file(I learned that from a certain YouTube source). So it was my intention to write those two Sys.out.printf(//Codes) into the line, It successfully did on first button click, but it didn't work upon other successive button clicks. But anyway, The resource you tagged was highly helpful.

Comment: @Abdul-razaqTwaha `System.setout(ps)` replaces your standard output stream (the thing you use to print to the screen) with the specified `PrintStream` which is unadvisable at the best of times, but since `PrintStream` has the same functionality that `System.out.println` would provide, it seems like a waste of effort and a pointless exercise which simply ruins any possibility of you providing print statements out to the console, which could be used to provide debug information or prompts to the user, but since you close the underlying stream, it just breaks the underlying API

Comment: @JRowan I tried moving it but the problem is still there it now increases the iteration number( the i++) but the data aren't updated. Should I not close the streams? (Data is only updated on the first submission but not updated on other submissions)

Comment: Okay Thanks. I have gotten your point @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method like so,

```
public void fileStoring() throws Exception {
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\data\\Mustard.txt", true);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter)) {
            if (i == 1) {
                printWriter.printf("%-10s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", "Sno.", "First Name", "Surname", "Reg.No",
                        "Program of Study");
            }
            printWriter.printf("%-10d %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", i, txtFname.getText(), txtSname.getText(),
                    txtRegNo.getText(), txtPos.getText()).toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle the exception here.
        }

        i++;
    }
```

Why you are not getting desired results is you initialize the stream inside the constructor and then close the stream after the first write.

```
fw.close();
ps.close();
```

Then the subsequent writes will fail. To counteract that, you need to create a new stream each time you write to the file (i.e. inside this method itself, not inside the constructor), and then close it. Also notice that you need to write header only at the beginning, and your implementation does not handle that too.

Comment: The code you provided has successfully worked as I wanted it to. I highly appreciate your help, sir.

Comment: @Abdul-razaqTwaha You can either upvote and/or mark it as the answer or downvote it. That's the practice we follow here. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

It has worked Successfully, I highly appreciate your contributions.

Below is the edited code, after your suggestions:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;

public class StudentAssignment extends JFrame {

private JLabel lblFname, lblbSname, lblRegNo, lblPos;
private JButton btnsubmit;
private JTextField txtFname, txtSname, txtRegNo, txtPos;
private JPanel panel1, panel12, panel3, panel4,panel5;
private int i = 1;

public StudentAssignment() throws Exception{
    componentInitialization();
    setVisible(true);
    actionListeners();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void componentInitialization(){
    setBounds(200, 200, 300, 300);
    setTitle("Mustard's Frame");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    lblFname = new JLabel("First Name");
    txtFname = new JTextField(10);
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(lblFname); panel1.add(txtFname);

    lblbSname = new JLabel("Surname");
    txtSname = new JTextField(10);
    panel12 = new JPanel();
    panel12.add(lblbSname); panel12.add(txtSname);

    lblRegNo = new JLabel("Registration Number");
    txtRegNo = new JTextField(10);
    panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.add(lblRegNo); panel3.add(txtRegNo);

    lblPos = new JLabel("program of study");
    txtPos = new JTextField(10);
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.add(lblPos); panel4.add(txtPos);

    btnsubmit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    panel5 = new JPanel();
    panel5.add(btnsubmit);

    add(panel1); add(panel12);
    add(panel3); add(panel4);
    add(panel5);

}

public void actionListeners(){

    btnsubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

            try {
                fileStoring();
            }catch (Exception exc){

            }

            clearFields();
        }
    });
}

public void fileStoring() throws Exception {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Mustard.txt", true);
         PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter)) {
        if (i == 1) {
            printWriter.printf("%-10s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", "Sno.", "First Name", "Surname", "Reg.No",
                    "Program of Study");
        }
        printWriter.printf("%-10d %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", i, txtFname.getText(), txtSname.getText(),
                txtRegNo.getText(), txtPos.getText()).toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    i++;
}

public void clearFields(){
    txtFname.setText("");
    txtSname.setText("");
    txtRegNo.setText("");
    txtPos.setText("");

    txtFname.requestFocus();
}

public static  void  main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    StudentAssignment obj = new StudentAssignment();
}
```

}